# Unable to prevent node from crashing and to send an error in a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Connection.js

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "xxxxx.amazonaws.com",
  user: "admin",
  password: "xxx",
  database: "xxx",
  multipleStatements: true,
});

var connect=()=> return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

  mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      
      reject ("Failed to connect")
    }
    else{
      resolve ("Connected")
    }
  });

})

module.exports = { mysqlConnection,connect};
```

server.js

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  
  var fetchDetail = `xxxx`
   
  connect()
    .then((result)=>{
      console.log(result)
      mysqlConnection.query(fetchDetail, (error, result, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfull");
          res.send(result);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
     
      res.send(err)
    })
  }
);
```

If I hit the URL when the internet is closed, I want to handle the error that occurs due to connection not established and send this error as a response so I can handle it on the frontend. But what is actually happening is that my node server got crashed with the error and its not sending the err as a response.
Am I handling it in the wrong way?
What else should I do.

Comment: What is the error? Did you add the `catch` block on `connect` method?

Comment: @Piyush Raj, can you include the error message in the description? However it seems that Manuel Spigolon is right and the error comes from `mysqlConnection.connect()`

Comment: Error is from the connect I have just send it in a reject so I can catch it and send a response.

Comment: The error comes when we are unable to connect to the instance I have put this in reject so I can catch it.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  
  var fetchDetail = `xxxx`
   
  connect()
    .then((result)=>{
      console.log(result)
      mysqlConnection.query(fetchDetail, (error, result, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfull");
          res.send(result);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
     let e=new Error("Some thing went wrong")
     e.status=500;
    next(e)

    })
  }
);

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

I have read the documentation how to handle error in Express from an asynchronous function.
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html